# Blitting non-rectangular sprites with Pygame, Python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm currently making a game, in which I load the sprites and backgrounds from images (PNG) using the `pygame.image.load()` function.

My problem is that not all of my sprites are rectangular - and because of that they leave ugly white-space on the background that I blitted them on to.
On the image below, the white is part of the ship sprite, however I would want it to blend in with the background.

[image]

Is there an easy way to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the ship image itself is transparent? I've managed to load transparent .pngs just fine. Also, what software did you use to make that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If image has transparent background (some pixels are transparent) (PNG) then you have to use [convert_alpha()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)

```
 image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
```

If image has no transparent background (GIF, JPG) then you can use [set_colorkey()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey) and pygame will treat selected color as transparent.

```
 image = pygame.image.load(filename).set_colorkey(color)
```

Many sprites images use pink as key color

[image]

Comment: I tried using the convert_alpha(), but it didn't make any difference. Could it be because I made it on mspaint?

Comment: You have to use PNG with transparent pixels. If you see white background using image viewer then you don't have transparent background and `convert_alpha()` will not work. And then you can only use `set_colorkey(WHITE)` (where `WHITE = (255,255,255)`)

Comment: Ok, thank you... but how can I make an image with transparent pixels right in mspaint or some other software?

Comment: I don't have `mspaint` but I think you can't get transparent background in `mspaint`. You need [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), [paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html)  or any other bitmap program (or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) if you prefer to use vector object)